# Looking for a HLS/MPEG-DASH Quality selector that works with for videojs 7.5

Tags: video.js

I'm trying to find a quality selector for Videojs 7.5 that automatically lists the available bandwidth versions in a HLS and MPEG-DASH manifest. A bit like YouTube where you can select a quality, but without having to manually place resolutions in the embedding code.
I tried several options listed in https://videojs.com/plugins/ but they all seem to be made for much older versions.
Anybody an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it. https://www.npmjs.com/package/videojs-http-source-selector does the trick.
It fills in all resolutions retrieved from the manifest and it works with videojs 7.5.0
You need to install videojs-contrib-quality-levels.js as well.
With other quality level plugins, you have to fill in all resolutions yourself (dynamic), which I liked to avoid.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work in safari, with m3u8

Answer (score 1):

Use these libs. It automatically picks up the qualities. Works smoothly with dash or hls link.

```
<!-- Brightcove quality picker -->
<link href="//players.brightcove.net/videojs-quality-menu/1/videojs-quality-menu.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="//players.brightcove.net/videojs-quality-menu/1/videojs-quality-menu.min.js"></script>
```

Demo player here: https://sahilkashyap64.github.io/hls/index5.html

Comment: Is there version for videojs 8?

Comment: Demo:[JsFiddle for video.js 8](https://jsfiddle.net/Physcocybernatics/anw9pmzr/48/)

2 library used:  
 1.  [jb-videojs-hls-quality-selector](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jb-videojs-hls-quality-selector)
 2. [videojs-contrib-quality-levels](https://github.com/videojs/videojs-contrib-quality-levels)

Comment: if you want to use latest video.js check this quality selector, although the quality button are outside the video player
https://v8-8-0--videojs-preview.netlify.app/sandbox/quality-levels